# API for whereis Command in linux

Tags: linux, unix, c

Is there an API similar to the "whereis" command in UNIX that can be called from a C program to find out all instances of a given command?

Answer (score 3):

Use `getenv("PATH")` to get a list of `':'`-separated directory names. Look for the command name in each directory (e.g. using `stat()` or `access()`) and check if it's a regular file and can be executed. (If the directory name is empty, assume `"."` instead.) That's exactly what the `which` and `whereis` commands do.

The `execvp()` and `execlp()` functions automatically do PATH lookups when executing the given command, although it seems they do not manually check each path but just call `execv()`; if an error code is returned, they just try the next path.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different functions in C you can use to launch shell command from your program. I think you should particularly look in the exec(3) family.

Every example you may need are in the manual: `man 3 exec` in a terminal or here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec.

Hope this helps!